# How to reduce the Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext time?

Tags: java, spring, jboss

I know that this question is too vague for anyone to provide a solution but I can provide more details if required.

My web application is using spring and I have deployed it to JBoss server, while jboss start-up "Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext" is nearly taking 20 minutes. Am I having any options to reduce this? I have close to 300 beans in 20 or more xml files.

Please advice.

Comment: Are there any time consuming tasks in the bean (300 odd beans you mentioned) initialization stage ? I would suggest to enable `debug` logs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some Best practices TIPS for Spring, compare these steps to Your application.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/spring_optimization

Answer (score 1):

why don't specify lazy loading of beans. So they dont get created at Server startup

Comment: How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try searching lazy property in bean initialization

Answer (score 0):

It got reduced to 4 minutes after commenting out the following from run.conf.bat:

```
rem set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -agentpath:C:\yjp\YourKit-Java-Profiler-11.0.1\bin\win32\yjpagent.dll"
```

Comment: YourKit is an additional third party monitoring tool, not everyone uses it.

Comment: Where can I find this file ?